# Multiple sessions possible per user

Tags: java, http, authentication, session, cookies

If a user opens 2 web pages simultaneously they will create 2 sessions.

Usually this would not matter but it does create a problem for remember me functionality when attempting to rotate cookie tokens as recommended in the [persistent login cookie best practices](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/). There seems to be no way to rotate both cookies correctly where both sessions are opened simultaneously.

How can I resolve this?

I use Tomcat and Struts 1, but I think this is framework independent.

Comment: Does the user really get two sessions? He should have only one cookie for each site, so that one of the two sessions will clobber the other one. If you want the same user in the same browser to have multiple sessions, you cannot use cookies for that.

Comment: @Thilo, I don't want the user to get 2 sessions, but if he enters the website on 2 pages simultaneously they will create 2 sessions (each initial request would not have a session cookie so the response will give 2 different new session IDs).

Comment: yes, but the first of those session would not be used, right? All subsequent page accesses would use the second session ID.

Answer (score 1):

extending @Thilo answer He is correct, any subsequent access to other page will follow send the cookies for that domain. e.g open gmail,  login and now open gmail in other tab or window it send the cookie for that domain. since the cookie hold the session information on any subsequent request only session id/value will be changed.
You can check it using firebug and its extension fire-cookie.
On matter of avoiding remember-me problem as said in the link you specified it is more to design problem as how you are handling it.